# How to pass one-to-many relationship to context on objects.all() lookup as iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm having trouble trying to wrap my head around this. many-to-one relationships are well documented, but I can't find an example on how to pass all of the relationships of a model.objects.all() lookup to context.

I'm trying to do something like

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):

    image_file = models.ImageField()
    imageset = models.ForeignKey(ImageSet)


class ImageSet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length)
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Image, ImageSet

def images(request):
    imagesets = ImageSet.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'imagesets': imagesets})
```

### template.html

```
{% for imageset in imagesets %}
    {{ imageset.title }}
    {% for image in imageset.images  %}
        <img src="{{image.image_file.url}}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried `imagesets = ImageSet.objects.all().prefetch_related()` but it only seems to work for ManyToMany relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an instance of the `ImageSet` model, you can access the related images with...

```
images = my_imageset.image_set.all()
```

...so you can just change the template to...

```
{% for imageset in imagesets %}
    {{ imageset.title }}
    {% for image in imageset.image_set.all  %}
        <img src="{{image.image_file.url}}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

See the Django documentation on [Related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) for more information.

Comment: I fixed the url reference.

Comment: I used this and it worked.
for imageset in imagesets:
    imageset.images = imageset.image_set.all()

Answer (score 0):

### views.py will be like this:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Image, ImageSet

def images(request):
    t=get_template("template.html")
    imagesets = ImageSet.objects.all()
    image = Image.objects.all()
    html=t.render(Context({'imagesets':imagesets,'image':image}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

In template.html:

```
{% for image in imageset.images  %} line will not work as imageset.image does not
exist because Imageset model having only one field title so you cat't access that.
if you   want to access image field of Image model then from views.py you have to send
that object also.
and <img src="{{image.url}}" alt=""> will not work. where is your url field??
```

---------thanks-------